# Jetpack Compose - Modifier.fillMaxHeight() not applied if parent layout wraps content

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have following case in my app:

```kotlin
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(48.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            // ...
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_arrow_back),
                modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Text(
                text = "Title" + "\n" + "Expand" + "\n" + "Expand" + "\n" + "Expand",
            )
            // ...
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .width(48.dp)
            .fillMaxHeight()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Basically parent Row's height should be defined by how much text is inside middle column, and columns on the right and left should match Row's height to add some badge color and other icons. But from my tests it doesn't work this this way, and results is as follows:

[image]

Where red badge should match parent height. What's the idiomatic way do make this work?

Comment: The above provided code seems proper as per your expectations because the same code works fine for me and red badge takes full height. Can you share code if there is another parent component that causes the scenerio?

Comment: @MeghLath Hmm, I think the difference might be that this item is inside `Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()))`. I'll update the question

Answer (score 2):

Just set your parent Row's height to **IntrinsicSize.Max**

This will allow Row to fill up the available space up to its maximum intrinsic size, and it won't shrink below its intrinsic size if there is extra space available.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {
        // ...
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Text(
            text = item.title + "\n" + "Expand" + "\n" + "Expand" + "\n" + "Expand",
        )
        // ...
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, this actually works. But why setting height to parent row fixes the children composable heights? Parent row height was correct before I added `.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)`, but children were wrong. I'm rather confused right now.

Comment: Check out the documentation on this: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements#intrinsics-in-action
`fillMaxHeight()` usually would push the parent Composables to fill the max height of the screen. In your case, you have a scrolling container, which internally has infinite height. Thus, Jetpack Compose just ignores any `fillMaxHeight()` Modifiers when the parent has`wrapContentHeight()`.

Comment: @BenjyTec Thanks, I never had a chance to play with Intrinsics, nice learning experience for me!